# Authorizing Route for Multiple Roles in React

Tags: authentication, reactjs, routes

I'm following a tutorial for authenticating react routes and I can now allow users to access a route if `authenticated` is true.

routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute,Redirect } from 'react-router';

import App from './app';
import requireAuth from '../Authentication/require_authentication';

import Dashboard from '../Dashboard';
import Managers from '../Managers';
import Guests from '../Guests';
import Login from '../Login';

export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={requireAuth(Dashboard)} />
    <Route path="dashboard" component={requireAuth(Dashboard)} />    
    <Route path="advertisers" component={requireAuth(Managers)} />
    <Route path="properties" component={requireAuth(Guests)}/>
    <Route path="login" component={Login} />

  </Route>
);
```

require_authentication.js

```
/*HIGHER ORDER COMPONENT */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default function(ComposedComponent) {
  class Authentication extends Component {
    static contextTypes = {
      router: React.PropTypes.object
    }     

    componentWillMount() {
      if (!this.props.authenticated) {
        this.context.router.push('/login');
      }
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
      if (!nextProps.authenticated) {
        this.context.router.push('/login');
      }
    }          

    render() {
      return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { authenticated: state.auth.authenticated };
  }

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(Authentication);
}
```

When a user logs in they have this as the state in the localStorage:

```
userId: 1, 
userName:"Bob",
roleName:"Manager"
```

I'm still fairly new to composed components but I'm wondering if there's a way to not only authenticate but prevent users with specific roles from accessing routes. Eg. Managers should only be able to see the Manager route and Dashboard. Guests can only see Dashboard and Guests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible, you simply need to add a condition after checking authorization that would check if user's role allows to see the route it's trying to render, and if not it may redirect the user to a default route or a page that displays an error message.

Following the concept of your Higher Order Component in `require_authentication.js`, here's a modified version that should do what you want:

```
const checkPermissions = (userRole, router) => {
  if (userRole === "Manager") {
    if (!(router.isActive('/dashboard') ||
          router.isActive('/manager'))) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};

export default function(ComposedComponent) {
  class Authentication extends Component {
    static contextTypes = {
      router: React.PropTypes.object
    }     

    componentWillMount() {
      if (!this.props.authenticated) {
        this.context.router.push('/login');
      } else if (!checkPermissions(this.props.user.role, this.context.router)) {
        this.context.router.push('/');
      }
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
      if (!nextProps.authenticated) {
        this.context.router.push('/login');
      } else if (!checkPermissions(this.props.user.role, this.context.router)) {
        this.context.router.push('/');
      }
    }          

    render() {
      return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      authenticated: state.auth.authenticated,
      user: state.auth.user
    };
  }

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(Authentication);
}
```

An implementation of the `checkPermission` function may be different and more configurable, the one from the example is just to demonstrate the idea.

I assumed that you have an authorized user data in your state inside the `auth` object. It may be changed depend on where user's data is stored in fact.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! I'd also recommend to check out existing packages as this functionality is pretty standard. For example: `redux-auth-wrapper` (https://github.com/mjrussell/redux-auth-wrapper) seems to have very similar idea.

Comment: Concerning your questions about `/` path, router's `isActive` method accepts a second parameter that makes it to match an exact path. So try to use `router.isActive('/', true)` for checking access to the index component.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks again!